# How to use exclusive wildcard in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I am using Mac OS Big Sur 11.4 and recently switched to zsh, but I got some trouble using wildcard in it. Suppose I have a directory with files
`1 2 3 1file 2file file1 file2 file3` and I want to list the files not starting with numbers. In bash it works fine as follows

```
Steves-Mac:test hengyuan$ cd test/dir3/
Steves-Mac:dir3 hengyuan$ ls
1     1file 2     2file 3     file1 file2 file3
Steves-Mac:dir3 hengyuan$ ls [[:digit:]]*
1     1file 2     2file 3
Steves-Mac:dir3 hengyuan$ ls [![:digit:]]*
file1 file2 file3
```

However, I got the following results in zsh

```
➜  dir3 ls
1     1file 2     2file 3     file1 file2 file3
➜  dir3 ls [[:digit:]]*
1     1file 2     2file 3
➜  dir3 ls [![:digit:]]*
zsh: event not found: [
```

Why did I get such strange results and how to fix them? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With zsh `!` invokes history expansion. You can use `[^...]` instead which means the same thing as `[!...]`. You can also disable history expansion by either quoting `[\!...]` or using the special sequence `!"` which disables history expansion fully for the current command line.

So these are all equivalent:

```
ls [^[:digit:]]*
ls [\![:digit:]]*
ls !" [![:digit:]]*
```

To completely disable history expansion you can run `setopt nobanghist`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, it indeed works!